# How do I schedule an audio file to play automatically in pygame after the first song ends?

Tags: python, pygame

I tried using the queue function, but

```
pygame.mixer.music.queue(filename)
```

doesn't seem to be working.

Here is the code I use to run my mp3 file:

```
def playmusic(self):
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(self.music_link+self.files[self.file_index])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    self.pausedmusic = 0
    self.file_index = self.fileindex + 1

    pygame.mixer.music.queue(self.music_link+self.files[self.file_index])
```

I tried to use events but got no solution from it either.

And if I use this code,

```
while(pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()):
    continue
self.playmusic()
```

the Tkinter GUI is unresponsive but the song keeps playing and it plays the next song automatically, too, keeping my player unresponsive till all songs are played.

I'm using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 2):

Put your music files (paths) into a list, define a custom userevent and call [`pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(YOUR_USEREVENT)`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent). Then pygame will add this event to the event queue when a song is finished and you can execute some code to change the index of the current song. In the example below you can either increment the index by pressing the right arrow key or wait until a song is finished (the `SONG_FINISHED` event is emitted) and the program will choose a random song (index).

```
import random
import pygame as pg


pg.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))

# A list of the music file paths.
SONGS = ['file1.ogg', 'file2.ogg', 'file3.ogg']
# Here we create a custom event type (it's just an int).
SONG_FINISHED = pg.USEREVENT + 1
# When a song is finished, pygame will add the
# SONG_FINISHED event to the event queue.
pg.mixer.music.set_endevent(SONG_FINISHED)
# Load and play the first song.
pg.mixer.music.load('file1.ogg')
pg.mixer.music.play(0)


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    song_idx = 0  # The index of the current song.
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                # Press right arrow key to increment the
                # song index. Modulo is needed to keep
                # the index in the correct range.
                if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                    print('Next song.')
                    song_idx += 1
                    song_idx %= len(SONGS)
                    pg.mixer.music.load(SONGS[song_idx])
                    pg.mixer.music.play(0)
            # When a song ends the SONG_FINISHED event is emitted.
            # Then just pick a random song and play it.
            elif event.type == SONG_FINISHED:
                print('Song finished. Playing random song.')
                pg.mixer.music.load(random.choice(SONGS))
                pg.mixer.music.play(0)

        screen.fill((30, 60, 80))
        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: I recommend to use ogg files instead of mp3s, because pygame has trouble with the mp3 format and it's also a proprietary format what means you can be forced to pay license fees.