# Pygame Playlist Continuous in the Background

Tags: python, background, pygame

I'm trying to get background music for my game, but I can't seem to figure it out perfectly. I've used pygame in the past, but it was only for one song during the credits of my game. 
I want the playlist to play continuously picking each track randomly. I've managed to get this working in a separate test file. I will post this code down below.

The problem is when I call this function in my main game, the music plays the first track, and then stops. If I put in

```
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    continue
```

It just plays the music and doesn't let me play the game. I want it to loop continuously through the playlist while the user plays the game (it's a text based game so it uses `raw_input()` a lot.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.mixer.init()

_songs = [songs, are, here]

_currently_playing_song = None

def music():
    global _currently_playing_song, _songs
    next_song = random.choice(_songs)
    while next_song == _currently_playing_song:
        next_song = random.choice(_songs)
    _currently_playing_song = next_song
    pygame.mixer.music.load(next_song)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

while True: ## This part works for the test, but will not meet my needs
    music() ## for the full game.
    while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        continue
```

(P.S. I learned python through Zed Shaw's "Learn Python The Hard Way" so my game structure uses the Engine and Map system from the book)

Comment: [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45597549/6220679) that shows you how to play a random song if the last one is finished or cycle through a list of songs by pressing the right arrow key.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a thread to play music in the background.

```
import threading
musicThread = threading.Thread(target=music)
musicThread.start()
```

If you ever want to stop the music without closing your game, you should kill the thread.

Comment: This is not necessary since pygame will create a thread for music automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a [pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent) which get posted in the event queue when the music finishes. Then you just choose another song. Something along these lines:

```
import os
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

SIZE = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 720, 460
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)

MUSIC_ENDED = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(MUSIC_ENDED)


BACKGROUND = pygame.Color('black')


class Player:

    def __init__(self, position):
        self.position = pygame.math.Vector2(position)
        self.velocity = pygame.math.Vector2()

        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.rect =  self.image.get_rect(topleft=self.position)

        self.image.fill(pygame.Color('red'))

    def update(self, dt):
        self.position += self.velocity * dt
        self.rect.topleft = self.position


def load_music(path):
    songs = []
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if filename.endswith('.wav'):
            songs.append(os.path.join(path, filename))
    return songs


def run():
    songs = load_music(path='/Users/Me/Music/AwesomeTracks')

    song_index = 0  # The current song to load
    pygame.mixer.music.load(songs[song_index])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    song_index += 1

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    player = Player(position=(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2))

    while True:
        dt = clock.tick(30) / 1000

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    player.velocity.x = -200
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    player.velocity.x = 200
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    player.velocity.y = -200
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    player.velocity.y = 200
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    player.velocity.x = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    player.velocity.y = 0
            elif event.type == MUSIC_ENDED:
                song_index = (song_index + 1) % len(songs)  # Go to the next song (or first if at last).
                pygame.mixer.music.load(songs[song_index])
                pygame.mixer.music.play()

        screen.fill(BACKGROUND)

        player.update(dt)
        screen.blit(player.image, player.rect)

        pygame.display.update()

run()
```

So the actual solution is just 3 parts

1. Create an event `MUSIC_ENDED = pygame.USEREVENT`.
2. Tell pygame to post the event when a song finishes `pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(MUSIC_ENDED)`
3. Check for the event in the event queue 
   `for event in pygame.event.get(): if event.type == MUSIC_ENDED:`

And then you're free to do whatever you desire.

Comment: @Macimoar this is the right answer and you really don't need `threading`. I don't know why the other one has more upvotes. You can accept your favorite answer by clicking on the checkmark to mark this question as solved.

Comment: This solution works well for the playlist to repeat, but it doesn't allow me to play the game while the music is playing (I only have a blinking cursor and the music continues playing until I do an interrupt). I'm not exactly sure why though.

Comment: @Macimoar This `run` function is expected to be a part of your main game loop. Running this code by itself will do nothing more than play music repeatedly. The actual solution to the problem is that you put events into the event queue in your game whenever the music stops so that you can change the song to whatever is appropriate.

Comment: @Macimoar I threw together a more complete example to demonstrate my point. All you do is checking for the `MUSIC_ENDED` event in the event loop, and if it's there you play another song. Then you could play a random song, choose from a playlist, go to the next song or stop the game as a game over event.