# How can a looping pygame.mixer playlist be set playing in the background?

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I've got a playlist of `.ogg` music files and I wanna set them playing in the game background on a big playlist loop. So, once all of the music files have been played by `pygame.mixer`, it loops back to the beginning to start again.

However, when I load the first track, set it playing and then add the other tracks to the queue, only the first track plays. I'm not sure how to get the queue to loop. What am I doing wrong?

```
playlist = ["2.ogg", "3.ogg", "1.ogg"]
pygame.mixer.init(frequency = 48000)
pygame.mixer.music.load("1.ogg")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
for track in playlist:
    pygame.mixer.music.queue(track)
```

Comment: is this all your code? do you do something else with `mixer.music` ?

Comment: Yup, that's all the code.

Comment: as I read documentation I think it can keep only one file in queue - but I didn't check it. Maybe [mixer.music.set_endevent()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent) can be useful to run function (in `for event` loop) which starts next track.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45597549/6220679

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to use [queue()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.queue) but it doesn't work for me.
Maybe it needs `for event` loop to work but it doesn't work for me too.

In documentation below [queue()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.queue) I found this comment:

> This method only queues one music file.
>   If you call it and there already is a queued file, it will be overrided.

so queue is not so usefull.

---

I use [pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent) with `for event` loop to start next track

```
import pygame

# define own event type
NEXT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1

playlist = [
    'track_one.ogg',
    'track_two.ogg',
    'track_three.ogg',
    'track_four.ogg',
]

tracks_number = len(playlist)
current_track = 0

pygame.init() # need it for event loop
#screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600)) # it can be useful to stop program 

pygame.mixer.init(frequency = 48000)

# start first track
pygame.mixer.music.load(playlist[current_track])
pygame.mixer.music.play()

# send event NEXT every time tracks ends
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(NEXT) 

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == NEXT:

            # get next track (modulo number of tracks)
            current_track = (current_track + 1) % tracks_number

            print("Play:", playlist[current_track])

            pygame.mixer.music.load(playlist[current_track])
            pygame.mixer.music.play()


pygame.quit()
```