# How to play the next song in file after the song is finished automatically using pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, audio-player

I'm making a music player using pygame.
But I cannot understand how to play the next song automatically after the previous song is finished.
My program is reading all mp3 files in a selected folder first.
Can you tell me how to do it?

```
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
import os
import pygame

directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
os.chdir(directory)
song_list = []
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith('.mp3'):
         song_list.append(file)
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(song_list[0])
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

I want to play the next song after the first song in finished automatically.

Comment: Here's a duplicate question with an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45597549/6220679). I can't mark this question as a duplicate, because my answer has zero upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

The files could be played in the initial for loop and you don't need to have them in a list then play them.

Regarding playing the mp3 files you need to wait for the music to play before exiting. And after finishing each files you can start playing the next one in the same way.

```
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog
import os
import pygame

directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
print("Loding files from directory:", directory)
os.chdir(directory)
pygame.mixer.init()
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith('.mp3'):
        print("Playing file:", file)
        pygame.mixer.music.load(file)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        # Wait for the music to play before exiting 
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():   
            pygame.time.Clock().tick(5)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. This way can be successful in playing songs continuously. 
But I want to put the filenames into a list to show these filenames on a listbox.
Are there any ways to store all filenames into a list and play them?
Any interfaces cannot be shown this way.

Comment: @spider_hand For that you can store the files in a list and then have a loop to iterate aver all the files like you did in your initial code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can select any song in the directory through Listbox and can play it too.

if you want to play all song one by one, You can add another button say 'Play_all' and assign the code by @saloua to that button.

ringtone folder is placed inside the same folder where this "audio_player.py" is present.

```
#audio_player.py
import os
import tkinter as tk
import pygame

def songs_list():
    files = [file for file in os.listdir('ringtone')]
    List = []
    for file in files:
        List.append(str(file))
        #print(file)
    #print(List)
    return List

def play(song_name):

    song_name_label['text'] = "Now Playing: " + song_name
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load("./ringtone/" + song_name)
    print("Playing:", song_name)
    pygame.mixer.music.play()

window = tk.Tk()
window .title("Any Name")
Height = 720
Width = 1080

# define size of window
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bg='#3cd1fa',  height=Height, width=Width)
canvas.pack()

# play button **************************************************
play_button_frame = tk.Frame(window)
play_button_frame.place(relx=0.40, rely=0.88, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.10)

play_button = tk.Button(play_button_frame, text="Play", font=25, fg='#d1d1d1', bg='black',
                        command=lambda: play(listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))  )
play_button.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.005, relheight=0.98, relwidth=0.49)


#list box (playlist) *************************************************
listbox_frame = tk.Frame(window, bg='green')
listbox_frame.place(relx=0.7, rely=0.2, relheight=0.6, relwidth=0.29)

listbox = tk.Listbox(listbox_frame, bg="white", selectmode='ACTIVE')
listbox.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.01, relheight=0.98, relwidth=0.98)

# song name *****************************************************************
song_name_frame = tk.Frame(window, bg='white')
song_name_frame.place(relx=0.20, rely=0.1, relheight=0.05, relwidth=0.60)
song_name_label = tk.Label(song_name_frame,font=("times now roman", 10))
song_name_label.place(relx=0.0, rely=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1)

# PLaylist, to display song in the list
playlist = songs_list()
for item in playlist:
    listbox.insert(tk.END, item)
# auto selecting 1st element of list box
listbox.selection_set( first = 0 )

window.mainloop()
```