# Loop over a list containing path to sound files

Tags: python, pygame

So what I was planning to do was loop over a list which contains path to my sound files and play them using pygame.mixer module in python, but when I did this the problem I encountered was pygame always play the last most index path file from the list, and rest were skipped. Example if my list contains 2 items:

```py
music_list = ['abc.mp3', 'gef.mp3']
for music_index in range(len(music_list)):
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load(music_list[music_index])
    mixer.music.play()

then it never plays abc.mp3 file and directly plays the last file gef.mp3
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve by this? Do you want to make sort of a playlist? If yes, check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596245/how-do-i-schedule-an-audio-file-to-play-automatically-in-pygame-after-the-first

Comment: try adding a `time.sleep` after the `play()`. You're playing both files, just immediately one after the other

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because play() method does not bloc your code, so your code will continue once you have lauched the music. Therefore, you will start to play the first music and immediately after, you will launch the second one. You end up skipping all the musics, and only playing the last one.

Comment: This is correct, `pygame.mixer.music.play()` (see docs [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.play)) is not blocking and the next song starts to play as soon as it is called, so only the last song will actually get played by the loop. 

From the docs for `play()`: *"This will play the loaded music stream. If the music is already playing it will be restarted."*

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a range to iterate over items of a list in python, simply using:

```
for music in music_list:
     ...
     mixer.music.load(music)
     ...
```

will do the trick.

As per why your code does'nt work it's most likely because you can't play two songs at the same time so the last song is played "over" the first ones.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pygame.mixer.music.queue()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.queue) to load sound files and queue it:

```py
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load('abc.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
mixer.music.queue('gef.mp3')
```