# The problem is that I can't play 2 sounds in a row (even with music.queue) it only plays 1 music and the programme stops, any idea?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a program that plays a list of music in a row until I press a button to stop it, for this I want to use pygame.mixer.music.
The problem is that I can't play 2 sounds in a row (even with music.queue) it only plays 1 music and the programme stops:
I have tried it:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load("music1")
pygame.mixer.music.queue("music2")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

but nothing's working.

Comment: The docs say to use `queue` and `play` in the other order. Does that help?

Comment: ... see the answers to [Loop over a list containing path to sound files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63488105/loop-over-a-list-containing-path-to-sound-files/63488275#63488275)

Comment: yes thank you, but the problem still persist, this only play the second song and never the first one !

Answer (score 1):

`pygame.mixer.music.play()` is not blocking

so the program is finishing and exiting before the second item in the queue is processed.

try:

```
import time

pygame.mixer.music.load("music1")
pygame.mixer.music.queue("music2")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(60) # or however long you need to wait for the next song to play
```

If you want the program to exit when the music stops you can either poll the `get_busy` state of the mixer or you can register a callback to the `end_event` that is called when a queue finishes

What you want is a loop that continues running regardless of the state of the queue, so:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("music1.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.queue("music2.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
paused = False
done = False
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.mixer.music.stop()
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: #press a key to pause and unpause
            if paused:
                pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
                paused = False
            else:
                pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                paused = True
        clock.tick(25)

pygame.quit()
```